# Find rank of AB, given that A has linearly independent columns and B has rank 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I'm trying to prove to myself that given...

- Matrix A, which has linearly independent columns, and at least 2 columns...
- Matrix B, which has rank of 2

Their product, AB, will have rank of 2. I believe this is because...

- Matrix B has two linearly independent columns.
- Each column of AB will be a combination of the columns of A
- When multiplying matrix A by matrix B, each of the two independent columns of B will create a unique combination of the columns in A.

Is this true? If so, can this be made more rigorous? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but I don't quite follow your line of reasoning

Comment: @MattSamuel good point! Edited the question accordingly

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Let me try one more time:

- Each column of AB is simply a combinations of the columns of A. This is because multiplying a matrix by a vector is equivalent to taking a linear combination of the columns of A.
- There are two linearly independent columns in B. When we multiply A by these columns, we end up with two vectors which are linearly independent to each other.

Does this make sense? This is the part I'm trying to prove to myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be made more rigorous/clear, here's how I would do it. Note that it does require thinking about the linear transformations represented by the matrices. I will use abuse notation slightly and use $A$ and $B$ to refer to both the matrices and the linear transformations they represent.

1. $\newcommand\im{\operatorname{im}}\dim \im B = 2$
2. $\im AB = A(\im B)$
3. $A$ is injective (since the columns are linearly independent), so $$\newcommand\rk{\operatorname{rank}}\rk(AB)=\dim \im AB = \dim A(\im B) = \dim\im B = \rk(B) = 2$$

Note that this says more generally that if $A$ has linearly independent columns, then $\rk(AB)=\rk(B)$. Also, I tried to keep the proof as close to what you wrote as possible, to make it clear how it rigorizes what you wrote, but it's probably not the most clear formulation of the proof.